# Laravel - How to use variable in view from a return Redirect?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel and am trying to play around with it's features.  However, I'm stuck on being able to use the `$username` variable

In my `UserController` class I have the following method:

```
public function handleRegister()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = Input::get('email');
    $user->username = Input::get('username');
    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->save();
    return Redirect::to('login')->withInput(array('username', $user->username));
}
```

This portion of my code works perfectly since when I `var_dump(Input::Old())` using 'Jon' as the username, the following is returned for /login:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "username" [1]=> string(3) "Jon" }
```

For the username input field for /login, I attempt to use the value using:

```
value="{{ Input::old('username') or '' }}"
```

However, the input field's value is always ''.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

After chaning the return value to the following:

```
return Redirect::to('login')->withInput(Input::only('username'));
```

and attempting to retrieve the value:

```
value="{{ Input::old('username') }}
```

Instead of 'Jon', the username field's value is set to 1.

I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the variable "input" with the magic function "with", and you are affecting an array to this variable, so in blade template you can access it with the following code :

```
// If you want to keep the recent post inputs, use withInput without parameters
return Redirect::to('login')->withInput();
// and then use this code to echo it
 {{ Input::old('username') }}
```

But I guess it would be better if you use Laravel's From and model binding like so :

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update', $user->id)))
    {{ Form::label('username', 'Username : ') }}
    {{ Form::text('username') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

here the user will be binded to the object with the id in the route, for example : `users/1` Laravel will fetch the user with the id of 1 and bind it to your form. But if we're talking about authentication or creation, there's no model binding needed, just use the laravel's form :

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('yourRouteName')))
    {{ Form::label('username', 'Username : ') }}
    {{ Form::text('username') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Note that you can use model binding in your routes so when you will have access to the object directly in your controller, for example, I want to edit and object, and following the RESTFul architecture I'll have the following route :

```
Route::put('users/{id}', array('as' => 'users.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update'));
```

then in the controller, I'll try to retrieve the user having the id passed in the URL, but when using model binding, i'll get a user object in my controller, you can do so, first by making a change to your route :

```
// we create a model binding
Route::model('user', 'User');
// and we use it in our route instead of the id
Route::put('users/{user}', array('as' => 'users.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update'));
```

now in our controller we can accept a user, and do whatever we want with that object :

```
public function update($user)
{
    var_dump($user);
}
```

now when you have a link like : `users/4` fetching the user with the ID of 4 is done automatically.

Comment: It seems that $input is undefined.  I am using blade, however.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer.  I understand what you meant earlier and why $input should have been defined.  I tried this again using both return values and neither of them result in a $username that is defined.  What's more, is when I don't use withInput(), Input::old() is an empty array.  I must be missing something else.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah if you want the old input check out the syntaxe I added to the answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with some new information.  After chaning the return value for the redirect, the username's field value is set to 1 for some reason. Thoughts?

Comment: I you want to redirect the inputs posted with the form, you don't need to provide any parameter to withInput method.

Comment: I'm going to learn about model binding and see if that will result in a working solution.

Comment: did you try the `withInput()` without parameters ? ... goodluck.

Comment: Yes, the Input::old() method returns an array of the values, however, I am not able to access them using Input::old('username').  When using Input::old('username'), instead of the username's value, it returns 1.

Comment: If I declare `<?php $input = Input::old(); ?>` on the login view, then `$input['username']` works.  If I instead use Input('username'), it returns 1.

Comment: That's odd, then I guess if you use `Input::old()['username']` it should work too. To be honest I never used it, I use model binding, so I don't have to worry about it, I just use the withInput() in the controller and it's done automatically.

Comment: Since I'm trying to learn how to do this sort of stuff the 'right way,' I'd love for you to edit your answer to show how this would be done using model binding.  That, in the end, is what I will be doing as well.

Comment: Sorry for late replay @RaphaelRafatpanah, anyway, do you use Laravel's Form ? or you create your own HTML form ?

Comment: I created my own form.

Comment: Because the `Redirect::to('route')->withInput();` when you are using laravel's form, it populates the form with old data automatically.

Comment: I updated my answer sorry because I'm not organizing my ideas well enough.

Comment: Anytime @RaphaelRafatpanah ;)